# Can I enable/disable hyperlink on a record based on User's permission set in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a requirement to add hyperlinks to record name only for certain user with specific permission set.

html file:

```
  <a data-record-id={f.Id} onclick={handleClick} target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;{f.Name}</a>
```

js file:

```
@wire(getList)
listresults;

handleClick (event) {

    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: event.target.dataset.recordId,
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you share a little more detail on the specific permission? Is it access set on a profile/permission set, or something else?

Comment: I want to check whether a User has a specific Permission Set assigned or not. Based on that user should be shown hyperlink .

Comment: There's no short way to check permission set assignments in LWC. You would need to query the user's permission set assignment using the wire service, and enable/disable the link in JavaScript accordingly: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319607&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the result through wire services only whether that permission set is assigned or not, but how do I enable/disable the link in js/html. That is main concern. I am new to lwc.

Comment: Using a Custom Permission assigned via Permission Set is more maintainable than checking for Permission Sets by name.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new style class in your CSS file that disables the link:

```
.disabledlink {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Set up a variable that's blank by default:

```
linkStyleClass = "";
```

But gets set to "disabledlink" if the user does not have the permission set assignment:

```
@wire(checkPermissionSetAssignment)
wiredPermissionSetAssignmentCheck({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        // Not sure what data you're getting back, but you could do a check here if not done in the Apex method
        this.linkStyleClass = "disabledlink";
    }
}
```

And finally, set that variable as the style class value in your link that will be enabled/disabled by that variable's value:

```
<a data-record-id={f.Id} onclick={handleClick} target="_blank" class={linkStyleClass}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{f.Name}</a>
```